# How does Apple position its slideshow inside a fixed-position box?

Tags: html, css, margin, fixed-width

See [the iPhone page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Apple positions its slideshow within a wrapper:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="clip">
        <!-- Slideshow here -->
    </div>

    ...
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the wrapper.

```
#wrapper {
    height: 758px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}
```

However, inspecting the document through Firebug, I found that its slideshow is much larger, but it still manages to be displayed without scrollbars. How does it do that?

Here's the CSS for the slideshow:

```
#clip {
    background: url("http://images.apple.com/v/iphone/home/b/images/shadow_down.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 1px -400px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 1780px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` will hide scroll bars.

Comment: Can you explain to me how the funny margin values that are applied to `#clip` work?

Comment: Here's an example of something that you can do with them: http://jsfiddle.net/XVhyG/2/ The outer div is floated left, but the width is set to auto. That means that it should size itself to fit its content, plus the content's margins. The inner div has a negative right margin, which causes the outer div to take up less width than the inner one. Changing the margin-right to a margin-left is also interesting: http://jsfiddle.net/XVhyG/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's the `overflow` property with the `hidden` value.